# XAML bind SelectedItem to a DataContext.listbox reference

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, xaml-binding

I stuck in a Problem:
I have a `PopUp` window, its `DataContext` points to an object which holds a reference to a `ListBox` (reftolistbox).

I managed to create a working binding with this codebehind code:

```
private void ID_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Binding myBinding = new Binding("id");
        myBinding.Source = ((myclass)DataContext).reftolistbox;
        myBinding.Path = new System.Windows.PropertyPath("SelectedItem.Name");
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(ID, ComboBox.TextProperty, myBinding);
    }
```

I want to replace the above code with a XAML Solution,
here is a list i tried but no one worked.

```
<Combobox ...
     Text="{Binding Source=DataContext.reftolistbox, Path=SelectedItem.Name }"  
     Text="{Binding reftolistbox.SelectedItem.Name }"  
     Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.reftolistbox.SelectedItem.Name}"
```

Need a XAML Solution, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try this : Text="{Binding ElementName=reftolistbox, Path=SelectedItem.Name }"

Comment: i tried it already, dont work

Comment: can we have the full xaml? mainly for ComboBox and ListBox

Comment: Ahhhh good Point, it works now!, In my DataContext class. the reftolistbox was a public field and not a property, therefore i could setup a binding in codebehind but not in xaml

Answer (score 0):

XAML only binds to properties

```
DataContext:
              { public ListBox reftolistbox { get; set; } }

working binding in XAML:
              Text="{Binding reftolistbox.SelectedItem.Name }"
```